Finding general expression for symmetric trace-free tensors (STFs)
Given a symmetric $n$-tensor $I_{\alpha_1 ... \alpha_n}$, its tracefree version is given by
$$Q_{\alpha_1 ... \alpha_n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor} (-1)^k \frac{ \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{2k}}{\binom{2n}{2k}} \delta_{(\alpha_1 \alpha_2}\cdots\delta_{\alpha_{2k-1}\alpha_{2k}}I_{\alpha_{2k+1}...\alpha_n)\mu_1 \mu_1 ...\mu_k \mu_k}$$ where Einstein summation convention has been used i.e. repeated indices are summed over. The $()$ indicate symmetrization of indices: E.g. $A_{(ab)}=\frac{1}{2!}(A_{ab}+A_{ba})$, $A_{(abc)}=\frac{1}{3!}(A_{abc}+A_{bca}+A_{cab}+A_{bac}+A_{cba}+A_{acb})$,etc. and $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta symbol.
A derivation of this identity proceeds via taking the ansatz
$$Q_{\alpha_1 ... \alpha_n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right\rfloor} (-1)^k~ a_{2k}~\delta_{(\alpha_1 \alpha_2}\cdots\delta_{\alpha_{2k-1}\alpha_{2k}}I_{\alpha_{2k+1}...\alpha_n)\mu_1 \mu_1 ...\mu_k \mu_k} \tag{1}$$
$a_{2k}$ is determined via a recurrence relation satisfied by it. That, in turn, is found by noticing that the trace which is obtained by setting two of the indices (say $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$) to be equal contains terms having both $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ as indices of $I$ in the expansion of the $k$th term of the above series which cancel terms having atleast one index on the $\delta$s in  expansion of $(k+1)$th term of the series.
So we need to count the number of terms in the $k$th term of the series $(1)$ for which both the contracted indices lie with $I$, and also the number of terms in the $(k+1)$th term of $(1)$ which has one index on $I$, one index on a $\delta$ other on a different $\delta$, and both on same $\delta$. This counting is where I face the difficulty.
(1) The book I am reffering to for this calculation is Pirani's lectures on General Relativity. See pg. 21-22 of this PDF. I don't understand why there are $(n-2)!(n-2k)(n-2k-1)$ ways in which both contracted indices will lie with $I$. More specifically, I don't understand why is it not $(n-2)! \binom{n-2k}{2}$ but instead a factor of $2$ is multiplied. A similar factor of $2$ arises when counting the number of terms in the $k+1$ th term, where one contracted index lies on $I$. My guess was that permutations are being considered because the brackets consider them as such. But these factors of $2$ do not appear in the counting where both indices lie on $\delta$s E.g. Number of terms in which one index lies on the same $\delta$ is $(n-2)! (2k+2)$ for the $k+1$ th term. Where are these factors of $2$ coming from?
(2) The overall contribution from the $k$th term where both contracted indices lie on $I$ appears to be $$\frac{(n-2k)(n-2k-1)}{n(n-1)}a_{2k} ~\delta_{(\alpha_3 \alpha_4}\cdots\delta_{\alpha_{2k-1}\alpha_{2k}}I_{\alpha_{2k+1}...\alpha_n)\mu_1 \mu_1 ...\mu_{k+1} \mu_{k+1}} $$ i.e. for some reason they have divided the number of relevant terms $(n-2)!(n-2k)(n-2k-1)$ by $n!$. Such a $n!$ also arises in the $k+1$th term, and in the end it doesn't matter because we are setting the trace to zero. But just to be crystal clear, where is this $n!$ coming from?
The point of posting the nitty-gritty details of this question and not simply the counting part is because I am not sure whether I understand clearly what is being counted here, so I thought that the context might be relevant. Any help in understanding the counting or an alternative proof or some alternative references is appreciated because the result although elementary seems to be not very well known in literature.

Contracting the $k^{\rm th}$ term in the sum with $\delta^{\alpha_1 \alpha_2}$ yields four distinct types of terms from the average over permutations of the indices in braces.  First, there are terms where $\alpha_{1,2}$ are associated with the same $\delta_{a_{2j} a_{2j+1}}$ in the symmetrized product.  The proportion of terms of this type is $\frac{2k}{n} \frac{1}{n-1}$.  This proportion gets multiplied by $\delta_i^i = 3$ when computing the trace.  Second, there are terms where $\alpha_{1,2}$ are associated with distinct $\delta$'s in the symmetrized product.  The proportion of terms of this type is $\frac{2k}{n} \frac{2k-2}{n-1}$.  Third, there are terms where one $\alpha_{1,2}$ is associated with a $\delta$, and the other with $I$ in the symmetrized product.  The proportion of such terms is $2 \frac{2k}{n} \frac{n-2k}{n-1}$, where the factor of $2$ arises because either index $\alpha_{1,2}$ can be associated with a given factor in the symmetrized product.  Fourth, there are terms where $\alpha_{1,2}$ are both associated with $I$.  The proportion of such terms is $\frac{n-2k}{n} \frac{n-2k-1}{n-1}$.  One can check that these proportions, including the factor of $2$ but not the factor of $\delta_i^i = 3$, sum to unity, as they should.  When computing the trace, however, the first three types of term involve the same tensor with one less $\delta$ in the symmetrized product, while the fourth involves a tensor with one additional trace of $I$.  Including the factor of $\delta_i^i = 3$, this leads to the recursion relation
$$ (n-2k)(n-2k-1) a_k + (2k+2)(2n-2k-1) a_{k+1} = 0 $$
by comparing successive terms in the sum.  Together with $a_0 = 1$, this yields the correct formula from the top of the post.  The factor of $2$ does not arise for terms of type 4 because $\alpha_1$ is first taken to be any index of $I$ and then $\alpha_2$ is taken to be any of the remaining indices of $I$, and those indices of $I$ can be in either order, so all possible pairings are already included without needing to account for permutations of $\alpha_{1,2}$.  In contrast, for terms of type 3 $\alpha_1$ could be associated with a $\delta$ and $\alpha_2$ with $I$, or vice versa.
